# What could be preventing my alias from expanding in a shell script

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to set an alias in a script and then execute the alias later on in the script. I've verified that the file path that the alias contains is valid, and I've also set the shell script to expand aliases as well, yet the script still refuses to use the alias. What could I be doing incorrectly here?

Script:

```
#set location of parallel script and replace ~ with $HOME if necessary
parallellocation="~/newnnm/parallel"
parallellocation="${parallellocation/#\~/$HOME}"
#If the parallellocation variable is set and a parallel command is not currently available, 
#proceed with setting an alias that points to the parallellocation variable
if [ -r "$parallellocation" ] && ! command -v parallel &>/dev/null; then
        shopt -s expand_aliases
        alias parallel="$parallellocation"
        parallel
fi
```

Sample output:

```
./processlocations_new2.sh
./processlocations_new2.sh: line 98: parallel: command not found
```

Comment: Don't use `~` in the first place. Just use `$HOME`.

Comment: Your script doesn't make sense in my environment, so I cannot fully test it, but I find that `shopt -s expand_aliases` *does* cause bash to expand aliases in shell scripts for me.  I suspect your problem is something different, such as what your alias expands *to*.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems aliases ARE expanded in the normal script, but not in if-blocks, function bodies, `{` ... `}` blocks etc. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Not quite, @choroba.  I find that aliases are expanded in `if` blocks, provided that they are *defined* outside, and that the `expand_aliases` option is set outside.

Comment: @chepner that variable would normally be populated from a command line argument. I decided to allow support for ~ so that the script will be more flexible when it comes to user input. I just have the variable set statically for this particular example

Comment: Although it does not answer the question, at this point it is perhaps useful to quote the Bash manual: "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases."  I see no advantage whatever in struggling to make aliases work as desired in this particular case, when it appears that the problem can be solved by defining a function instead.

Comment: @choroba thanks! did not think to try that, that got things working

Comment: @JohnBollinger What would be the appropriate way to do this using a function? I did try doing that first but I was not able to get it working without relying on eval, so I decided to go down the alias route since it seemed like a cleaner solution

Comment: Hmmm…`alias` and 'clean' are not terms that often belong in the same sentence.  Silly question time: why don't you install `parallel` in a directory on `$PATH`?  Or create a symlink from a directory in `$PATH` to where the executable is installed (`ln -s ~/newnnm/parallel $HOME/bin`, for example)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my aim is to make the script portable. So you can copy it onto a different machine and run it, after which it will check to see if parallel is installed first, and in the event it is not, it will use the location that is specified in parallellocation

Comment: @lacrosse1991, I have included a function-based alternative in my completely-rewritten answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reflected in the comment record on the question, `bash` seems not to honor alias definitions or setting of the `alias_expand` option within the scope of an if block or other compound command.  The [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases) explains this:

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat
>   confusing. Bash always reads at least one complete line of input
>   before executing any of the commands on that line. Aliases are
>   expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed. Therefore,
>   ***an alias definition appearing on the same line as another command does
>   not take effect until the next line of input is read***. The commands
>   following the alias definition on that line are not affected by the
>   new alias. This behavior is also an issue when functions are executed.
>   ***Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the
>   function is executed, because a function definition is itself a
>   command***. As a consequence, aliases defined in a function are not
>   available until after that function is executed. ***To be safe, always
>   put alias definitions on a separate line, and do not use alias in
>   compound commands***.

(Emphasis added.)  The comments do not refer directly to shell options, but the same logic that says alias definitions within a compound command do not apply within the same compound command also implies that it is the value of the `expand_aliases` option in effect when the compound command is read that applies.

The question arose as to how to use a shell function instead of an alias for this purpose.  Here's one way:

```
altparallel="$HOME/newnnm/parallel"

parallellocation=
if command -v parallel >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  parallellocation="command parallel"
elif [[ -x "$altparallel" ]]; then
  parallellocation="$altparallel"
fi

# Runs parallel with the given arguments.  Uses the 'parallel' command
# found in the path if there is one, or a local one designated by
# $altparallel if that exists and is executable.  Exit status is that of
# 'parallel', or 1 if no 'parallel' command is available.
parallel() {
  [[ -z "$parallellocation" ]] && return 1

  # expansion of $parallellocation is intentionally unquoted
  $parallellocation "$@"
}
```

You source that from your environment setup scripts to get a `parallel` function defined that does what you want.

On the third hand, if all you want is a script that runs one version of parallel or the other, directly, then you don't need either a function or an alias.  Just figure out which you want to run, and run it, something like:

```
altparallel="$HOME/newnnm/parallel"

if command -v parallel >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  parallel "$@"
elif [[ -x "$altparallel" ]]; then
  "$altparallel" "$@"
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are a parse time feature. They work by substituting one string for another during parsing.

Commands are entirely parsed before they're executed, and this includes compound commands like `if`.

The effect of this is that any changes to the parser, like setting aliases, will not take effect in any of the possibly nested compound commands where the setting takes place.

For example, if you wrap your entire script in `{...}`, no aliases will work because it's now a giant compound command.

This is yet another reason why you should never use aliases outside `.bashrc`, and even then just sparingly. Use functions.

Answer (score -2):

You can enable/disable alias expansion with **shopt** within a bash script/command line.

```
$ shopt -u expand_aliases
```

- `-s` **S**et
- `-u` **U**nset

You can also use **unalias** to remove specific aliases (if you know them)

```
$ unalias <aliasname>
```

Be aware when you're using aliases in BASH srcipts, they aren't going to expand inside conditional constructs.
So while this one would work inside of a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -e expand_aliases
alias list1='ls -lhS'
list1
```

this one won't:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -e expand_aliases
alias list2='ls -lah'
if [ 1 ]; then
  list2
fi
```

So as the others pointed out in the comment section, use functions, or use **eval** to execute the command string stored in `$parallellocation`:

```
eval $parallellocation
```

Comment: Your answer isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I tought he'd like to disable aliasing! Corrected my answer accordingly.